# werkzeug.routing.BuildError BuildError: ('oauth_authorize', {'provider': 'twitter'}, None)

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm trying to add Login with twitter redirect in my login page. Which is called login.html.

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('oauth_authorize', provider='twitter') }}">Login with Twitter</a></li>
```

upon clicking that URL it throws me BUILDERROR.

```
BuildError: ('oauth_callback', {'provider': 'twitter'}, None)
```

Here is the code.

```
@user_blueprint.route('/authorize/<provider>')
def oauth_authorize(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return rredirect(url_for('main.home'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    return oauth.authorize()
```

That is my views.py the oauth_authorize function.
@user_blueprint.route('/callback/')

```
def oauth_callback(provider):
    if not current_user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    social_id, username, email = oauth.callback()
    if social_id is None:
        flash('Authentication failed.')
        return redirect(url_for('user.login'))
    user = User.query.filter_by(social_id=social_id).first()
    if not user:
        user = UserProfile(social_id=social_id, nickname=username, email=email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    login_user(user, True)
    return redirect(url_for('user.login'))
```

I've been trying to debug the problem.
I have a mixture feelings about the oauth.py code I have.

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service, OAuth2Service
from flask import current_app, url_for, request, redirect, session


class OAuthSignIn(object):
    providers = None

    def __init__(self, provider_name):
        self.provider_name = provider_name
        credentials = current_app.config['OAUTH_CREDENTIALS'][provider_name]
        self.consumer_id = credentials['id']
        self.consumer_secret = credentials['secret']

    def authorize(self):
        pass

    def callback(self):
        pass

    def get_callback_url(self):
        return url_for('oauth_callback', provider=self.provider_name,
                       _external=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_provider(self, provider_name):
        if self.providers is None:
            self.providers = {}
            for provider_class in self.__subclasses__():
                provider = provider_class()
                self.providers[provider.provider_name] = provider
        return self.providers[provider_name]


class FacebookSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FacebookSignIn, self).__init__('facebook')
        self.service = OAuth2Service(
            name='facebook',
            client_id='512038548997732',
            client_secret='a5a480e8da592d5c16feeee5426976b4',
            authorize_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize',
            access_token_url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token',
            base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/'
        )

    def authorize(self):
        return redirect(self.service.get_authorize_url(
            scope='email',
            response_type='code',
            redirect_uri=self.get_callback_url())
        )

    def callback(self):
        if 'code' not in request.args:
            return None, None, None
        oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
            data={'code': request.args['code'],
                  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                  'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()}
        )
        me = oauth_session.get('me?fields=id,email').json()
        return (
            'facebook$' + me['id'],
            me.get('email').split('@')[0],  # Facebook does not provide
                                            # username, so the email's user
                                            # is used instead
            me.get('email')
        )


class TwitterSignIn(OAuthSignIn):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TwitterSignIn, self).__init__('twitter')
        self.service = OAuth1Service(
            name='twitter',
            consumer_key='pNU7LEHOLEAJH3lQRNwOjiJMH',
            consumer_secret='WFe5DVdi5JZ6KtuyRWYP9BkC8905EUp0N56junLtde1vL5w2NR',
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/'
        )

    def authorize(self):
        request_token = self.service.get_request_token(
            params={'oauth_callback': self.get_callback_url()}
        )
        session['request_token'] = request_token
        return redirect(self.service.get_authorize_url(request_token[0]))

    def callback(self):
        request_token = session.pop('request_token')
        if 'oauth_verifier' not in request.args:
            return None, None, None
        oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
            request_token[0],
            request_token[1],
            data={'oauth_verifier': request.args['oauth_verifier']}
        )
        me = oauth_session.get('account/verify_credentials.json').json()
        social_id = 'twitter$' + str(me.get('id'))
        username = me.get('screen_name')
        return social_id, username, None   # Twitter does not provide email
```

This is a traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 125, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Ben/Desktop/flask_practise/project/user/views.py", line 81, in oauth_authorize
    return oauth.authorize()
  File "/Users/Ben/Desktop/flask_practise/oauth.py", line 86, in authorize
    params={'oauth_callback': self.get_callback_url()}
  File "/Users/Ben/Desktop/flask_practise/oauth.py", line 22, in get_callback_url
    _external=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 312, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 305, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1616, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method)
BuildError: ('oauth_callback', {'provider': 'twitter'}, None)
```

SOULUTION ----
Woops! I feel like an idiot. I had been changing file on a wrong directory. All I had to do was add the user_blueprint at my oauth.py file. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using Blueprints, in your Jinja template you'll need to call the endpoint like this

```
url_for('user_blueprint.oauth_authorize', provider='twitter')
```

Comment: Hey. I added blueprint. Now it doesn't give me that error but it returns me the same error when I click that button.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorize/twitter at that URL.  I'll update the main thread actually.